# .condarc file is regularly overwritten by something

Tags: python, anaconda

I manually changed the order of the channels in my .condarc file to give conda-forge the priority. However, something regularly overwrites this change and reverts the file to its default state. (Meaning, the defaults channel will be prioritized again.) Based on [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1456) I think the guilty party is the anaconda-navigator but I was not able to test it yet. Is there a way to make my change to the .condarc file permanent?

Edit: I just checked, indeed, starting anaconda-navigator reverts the channel priority list. Now, I just need to know how to prevent this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Anaconda-Navigator, if you go to File->Preferences the second item down is a checkbox labeled "Enable SSL Verification". If this is checked it will overwrite the .condarc file.

Sourced from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1456).